# Most efficient way to retrieve/update an object from a collection?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, iterator

I'm working with a silverlight datagrid that is bound to an observable collection of a business object.
We do not support inline editing of the objects within the grid but we do display a corresponding editing panel for the user selected row.
When the user submits the edits from this panel, I'm persisting the changes in the DB but I'd like the changes to also reflect in the grid.

I know that through the use of the observable collection and notify property changed that if I change the object that the selected row is bound to, the changes will display in the grid.

However, since I'm not inline editing, I need to search the observable collection for the object and make the change to the business object's instance in the observable collection.

I'd like to avoid having to loop through the collection to find said object but I'm worried this is the only real way.
There's no other more efficient, less performance-heavy way that I'm not aware of to retrieve an object from a collection correct? Other than simply to loop through until I hit it?

Comment: How do you populate the edit panel? Couldn't you just maintain a reference to whatever object is being displayed in the panel?

Comment: if it's anything like wpf, you bind the field of the object you are editing to the editing control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you bind your edit grid to the selected item of the display grid?  Since they are references this will push/pull changes into the observable collection which can then be persisted.

Comment: Possibly...I'll give that a shot.
Can you bind to more than a single selected items? Would the binding update all rows selected?

Comment: depends on what property you bind to on the datagrid. There is a SelectedItem property which is an datagridrow and there is a SelectedItems collection which is a collection of datagridrows. from that you can get the bound object if needed.

Comment: the way we're doing it is that the editpanel is completely dynamic. it's simply a listbox that is populated on the fly with user control templates (label + textbox, label + datetimepicker, etc.)
so as i'm creating these templates on the fly, i can set the binding of their textbox or datetimepicker, but then how do i bind that selected row's object? somehow bind it to the listbox that contains all the controls?

Comment: the listbox has a selected item property that will be the object (actually a reference to the object) from the bound observable collection.  Bind to that property.  Any changes you make to the object you get from the selected item property will be automatically made in the observable collection if two way binding is enabled in your binding statement.

Answer (score 0):

after having some critical exceptions happen that i couldn't keep track of i decided to avoid the databinding to the edit panel and go with Jeffrey L Whitledge's suggestion.
i'm maintaining a reference to the object displayed in the panel and with the notify changed, when i the user submits the update panel and i persist the changes to the business objects, i'm setting the changes to the grid row object that's bound.

thx guys